# How could I programmatically get all the job tracker and tasktracker information that is displayed by Hadoop in the web interface?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Cloudera's Hadoop distribution CDH-0.20.2CDH3u0.
Is there any way I could the information such as jobtracker status, tasktracker status, counters using a JAVA program running outside of hadoop framework? I tried listening using JMX but hadoop provides very less information regarding Jobtracker, tasktracker and datanode. It doesn't provide any JMX attributes related to running job state like map percent completion, reduce percent completion, task percent completion, attempt percent completion, counters status etc.

Futhermore I tried using the metrics logs dumped by hadoop. But it too doesn't contain any information regarding map/reduce percent completion, task percent completion.

I think, there should be some  alternative way to get all those stuffs.

Please do reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is correct but you can try HUE. I think HUE gives information about jobs. Since its open source you can see how they access job tracker and name tracker.

Comment: Hue is using a little plugin on the JobTracker to pull its information (running jobs, tasks, logs...) by Thrift RPC.

Comment: @RomainRigaux What is the plugin? Also, could you point to exactly where in the code the Thrift RPC is being made?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Hadoop API to access this information programmatically. In particular, instantiate `JobClient` with the suitable configuration for your cluster, and then you can use `getJob` on that instance to get a `RunningJob`. With that, you should be able to get to the detail you're looking for (following code is completely untested, but in the direction of the right idea I hope):

```
JobClient theJobClient = new JobClient(new InetSocketAddress("your.job.tracker", 8021), new Configuration());
RunningJob theJob = theJobClient.getJob("job_id_string"); // caution, deprecated
float mapProgress = theJob.mapProgress(); // similar for reduceProgress
// etc (see RunningJob)
```

You can also get the list of currently-running jobs with `theJobClient.jobsToComplete`, which returns an array of `JobStatus`, which should expose similar values (`mapProgress`, etc), and can provide the `JobID` instance you could use to get the `RunningJob` above (if you want to avoid the deprecated method).

Surely there are further options. Start with http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html for further details.

Comment: I don't think the JobClient or RunningJob objects will give all the data that the OP is requesting.