# How to get job pool info hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

Is it possible to get pool info from running job using any hadoop API? If not is it possible to do so with http get from any jobtracker location? or any other way?

Or can this class be instantiate or extend http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Pool.java.html ?

I'm using hadoop version 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could I programmatically get all the job tracker and tasktracker information that is displayed by Hadoop in the web interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620374/how-could-i-programmatically-get-all-the-job-tracker-and-tasktracker-information)

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate I'm asking specifically about pools because I've got everything else covered.