# How to access Hive log information

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs, hcatalog

I am trying to analyze the performance of the Hive queries. Though I was able to make Hive queries with Java but I still need to access the log information getting generated after each query. Instead of using a hack to read the latest log on the disk and using regex to extract the numbers I am looking for a graceful method if already available.

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

-lg

Answer (score 1):

Query execution details like Status,Finished at, Finished in  are displayed in Job Tracer, you can access job tracker programmatically  . Related info at this link

**[How could I programmatically get all the job tracker and tasktracker information that is displayed by Hadoop in the web interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620374/how-could-i-programmatically-get-all-the-job-tracker-and-tasktracker-information)**

Answer (score 0):

Once hive starts running a corresponding map-reduce job starts. The logs of this hadoop job can be found on the corresponding tasktracker on which each task runs.

Use [jobclient](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html) API to retrieve these logs programmatically.

Comment: Thanks KS. I was following the same approach but is currently stuck with the exception: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException". It happens while creating an object of JobClient. I made all the jackson jars available to my java program but still no luck. Are they to be placed on the Hive system?